# mongooseJS returning an object after update?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to return a document after updating it?

my current code looks something like this:

```
module.exports.updateEmail = function(id, data, callback) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate( id, {
        $set: { "email": email }
    }, callback);
}
```

how would I pull the User document and pass it back?

Comment: It looks like you need the traditional approach of retrieving the document with a findById after your update.

Comment: callback doesn't have user doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `{new : true}` update option, to return the updated document, the callback will have the updated document you can return it

```
module.exports.updateEmail = function(id, data, callback) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate( id, 
            {$set: { "email": email }},
            {new : true}, // to return updated document
            callback
    );
}
```